# When series converge conditional and absolute

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty~\frac{(-1)^nn^2+\ln^2n}{n^2\ln n}$$
 i see that its equal $\sum_{n=2}^\infty~\left(\frac{(-1)^n}{\ln n}+\frac{\ln n}{n^2}\right)$ . First I think about Leibniz but in this case $a_n<0$ when n=2. And no idea about second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence $\left(\frac1{\ln n}\right)$ is decreasing to $0$ so by the Leibniz's test the series 
$$\sum_n \frac{(-1)^n}{\ln n}$$
is convergent. Moreover we have
$$\frac{\ln n}{n^2}=_\infty\left(\frac1{n^{3/2}}\right)$$
hence the series
$$\sum_n \frac{\ln n}{n^2}$$
is convergent by comparison with a Riemann convergent series hence the given series is convergent.

Now since 
$$\left|\frac{(-1)^n}{\ln n}+\frac{\ln n}{n^2}\right|\ge \frac{1}{\ln n}-\frac{\ln n}{n^2}$$
and the series $$\sum_n  \frac{1}{\ln n}$$ 
is divergent by the integral test series then the given series isn't absolutely convergent.

Comment: Nicely written!